# Discriminator not used in SQL for one-to-many mapping in ColdFusion ORM

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, hibernate-mapping, coldfusion-9

Let's say I have the following entities:

**Store:**

```
component
{
    property name="Id" fieldtype="id" generator="native";
    property name="Name";
    property name="Fruits" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="Fruit" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan";
    property name="Vegetables" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="Vegetable" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan";
}
```

**Product.cfc**:

```
component table="Product" discriminatorcolumn="ProductType"
{
    property name="Id" fieldtype="id" generator="native";
    property name="Name";
    property name="Price";
    property name="Store" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="Store";
}
```

**Fruit.cfc**:

```
component table="Product" extends="Product" discriminatorvalue="Fruit"
{
    property name="HasVitaminC" type="boolean";
}
```

**Vegetable.cfc**:

```
component table="Product" extends="Product" discriminatorvalue="Vegetable"
{
    property name="IsGreen" type="boolean";
}
```

In other words, a `Store` contains a collection of `Fruits` and `Vegetables`, and `Fruits` and `Vegetables` extend the base component `Product`. I'm using table-per-hierarchy mapping with a discriminator column for the `Products`.

The issue I'm running into now is when I populate a store and try to get the `Fruits` or `Vegetables` collection:

```
var store = EntityLoadByPK("Store", 13);
var fruits = store.getFruits();
```

The SQL that it runs behind the scenes to grab fruits is:

```
select * from Product where store_id = 13;
```

As you can see, the discriminator is not used, and I get both fruits **and** vegetables. When I try to iterate through this collection, I will receive an error because a `Vegetable` is a type mismatch with `Fruit`.

However, if I try the inverse way where I start with `Fruit` and filter by a `Store`:

```
var store = EntityLoadByPK("Store", 13);
var fruits = EntityLoad("Fruit", {store=store});
```

It will run the correct SQL:

```
select * from Product where ProductType = 'Fruit' and store_id = 13;
```

**My question is**, what am I doing wrong here that allows the ORM to work correctly when I filter the fruits by store, but not correctly when I try to get the fruits collection for a store? Or have I stumbled across a bug?

**Edit:** Here is the CFM file I'm executing to reproduce this behavior:

```
<cfscript>
    ormReload();

    // create a new store
    store = EntityNew("Store");
    store.setName("Grocery Store");

    // create a new fruit and add it to the store
    fruit = EntityNew("Fruit");
    fruit.setName("Banana");
    fruit.setStore(store);
    store.addFruits(fruit);

    // create a new vegetable and add it to the store
    vegetable = EntityNew("Vegetable");
    vegetable.setName("Asparagus");
    vegetable.setStore(store);
    store.addVegetables(vegetable);

    // save the store
    EntitySave(store);

    // flush and clear out the session
    ormFlush();
    ormClearSession();

    // load the store and get its fruits collection, this will execute the
    // wrong SQL and return TWO items
    store = EntityLoad("Store")[1];
    fruits = store.getFruits();
    writedump(fruits);

    ormClearSession();

    // load the store and filter fruits by it, this will execute the
    // correct SQL and return only one item
    store = EntityLoad("Store")[1];
    fruits = EntityLoad("Fruit", {store=store});
    writedump(fruits);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: may wanna consider filing a bug to http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html

Comment: Bug report submitted. My guess is that it really is a bug, since I'm able to get it working fine using NHibernate with C#.

Comment: for now, maybe u can use `where="ProductType = 'Fruit'"` as a workaround?

Comment: That's the exact workaround I used, and it works except for one caveat: you can't use `lazy="extra"`. Because `lazy="extra"` will generate a `select count()` first followed by the actual `select` query, the `count` will return a different number than the `select`, and this trips up Hibernate.

Comment: @Henry By the way, thanks for all your help, on my other questions as well.

Comment: have u tried adding the `property name="Store" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="Store"` into both `Fruit` and `Vegetable`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4087/discussion-between-henry-and-daniel-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a single mapped association : the many-to-one association between a product and a store. The two one-to-many associations (store-vegetables and store-fruits) are both the inverse association of the single product-store association, which is not valid.

I'm not sure of the best solution, though. Moreover, I know what I can do in Java, but not in coldfusion. Look at adding a where clause or a filter to your collection mapping (see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.html and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Filter.html).

Or simply have a single store-products one to many association, and add two custom methods filtering the collection of products.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using HQL in the Store class to do this so something like:

```
function getFruits(){
  return ORMExecuteQuery( "
    from Product as p
    where p.class IN ( Fruit )
    and p.store = :Store ", 
    { Store=this } 
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. I got around it by adding a WHERE clause on the ONE side of my one-to-many relationship, as my target object has no knowledge of the other side of the join.

I agree that this is a bug. BTW, which version of CF are you running?

Also, have you had any luck defining your relationships as HBMXML and including it? This might reveal an implementation issue by Adobe. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/…

Comment: Why not edit your answer and add it rather than commenting on you own answer?